# Why am I getting a error in my Time series plot?

Tags: r, time-series

Im working of this dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

I am trying to plot number of reviews per day.

```
str(nycab$last_review) #since it is as charecter change to date
nycab$last_review <- lubridate::ymd(nycab$last_review)#change to date format

reviewsperday <- nycab %>%  #find number of reviews per day 
  group_by(nycab$last_review) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) 

reviewsperday %>%
  plot_time_series(nycab$last_review, freq,  #plot time series 
                   .interactive = interactive,
                   .plotly_slider = TRUE )
```

However when I run the last piece of code it gives me this error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `.value_smooth`.
x `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`
i Input `.value_smooth` is `auto_smooth(...)`.
```

Which confuses me as I know the df is of equal length. Is this because I have `NA's` in my date column?

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarise(freq = n())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being two fold. As there was `NA's` in the dataset and when you use `group_by` it changes the `col` back to character.

```
nycab <- na.omit(nycab)


reviewsperday <- nycab %>%  #find number of reviews per day 
  group_by(last_review) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) 

reviewsperday$last_review <- lubridate::ymd(reviewsperday$last_review) #change to date format

reviewsperday %>%
  plot_time_series(last_review, freq,  #plot time series 
                   .plotly_slider = TRUE )
```

This should not give you an interactive time series graph

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found a solution, but it seems that removing NA is all you need.

```r
reviewsperday %>% filter(!is.na(last_review)) %>%
  plot_time_series(last_review, freq,  #plot time series 
                   .interactive = FALSE,
                   .plotly_slider = TRUE )
```

Comment: True. And I also made the mistake of using lubridate before group_by. group_by seems to have changed the date back to character.